# Having a edge without arrow in mxGraph

Tags: angular, mxgraph

I'm in angular using mxGrpah library. I'm trynig to have two cells connected with an edge but i don't want an arrow either at the end or the start of the edge.

I've tried to make a style that makes the arrow size 0 with :

```
style[mxConstants.DEFAULT_MARKERSIZE] = 0;
style[mxConstants.ARROW_SIZE] = 0
```

i've also tried to set the SHAPE as a line :

```
style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.SHAPE_LINE;
```

But nothing seems to be doing what i want which is a simple straigth line.

If you have any idea, i would love to hear it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [endArrow](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxConstants-js.html#mxConstants.STYLE_ENDARROW) and [startArrow](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxConstants-js.html#mxConstants.STYLE_STARTARROW) styles

```js
style[mxConstants.STYLE_ENDARROW] = mxConstants.NONE;
style[mxConstants.STYLE_STARTARROW] = mxConstants.NONE;
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, must have missed this one !